# Error executing ScriptBlock from string

Tags: xml, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an xml of following type -

```
<Test>
<Address>
    <AddressType>Postal</AddressType>
    <Street>123</Street>
    <Suburb>Rhodes</Suburb>
</Address>
<Address>
    <AddressType>Commmunication</AddressType>
    <Street>345</Street>
    <Suburb>Liberty Grove</Suburb>
</Address>
```

My task is to get Street and Suburb pertaining to AddressType - Postal in the format Street, Suburb.

My script for doing this is as shown below -

```
$Path = "C:\Testing.xml"
$XPath = "/Test/Address[AddressType='Postal']"
$LeafNodes ="$($_.Street) , $($_.Suburb)"

$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load($Path)

$string = @"
select-xml -Xml "$($xml)" -XPath "$($XPath)" | 
        select -ExpandProperty Node |
        select @{N="FullAddress";E={"$LeafNodes"}} | 
        select -ExpandProperty FullAddress 
"@


$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($string)
.$ScriptBlock
```

Running the above block gives me a weird error. as seen below -

```
Select-Xml : Cannot bind parameter 'Xml'. Cannot convert the "System.Xml.XmlDocument" value of type 
"System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode".
At line:1 char:17
+ select-xml -Xml "System.Xml.XmlDocument" -XPath "/Test/Address[AddressType='Post ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Xml], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCom 
   mand
```

My actual task is that the LeafNode variables would be coming from another mapping file.

Say suppose that file requires the data to be Street;Suburb then $LeafNodes ,which I would be achieving using some string manipulation, would be as seen below

```
 $LeafNodes= "$($_.Street) ; $($_.Suburb)"
```

Can someone help me on how to tackle this conversion type failure? I cannot look for the option of storing the whole thing in another .ps1. My actual task involves finding and concatenating data nodes from lot of complex xml's.

EDIT-
Thanks har07 for pointing it out. I have now modified the script and the new error that I am getting while running the script.

Comment: As the error message suggested, you used the xpath instead of path to load the xml : `$xml.Load($XPath)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with lot of digging around and looking at alternatives I was able to manage a workaround. Here it goes -

```
$Path = "C:\Testing.xml"
$DesiredOutput = "*Street*,*Suburb"
$XPath = "/Test/Address[AddressType='Postal']" 

# variable to ensure only non special characters
# are identified
$Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$"

$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument


$xml.Load($Path)
#get the target node whose child elements are 
# needed to be manipulated
$targetNode = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath $XPath

# Split the desired output into an array
# here * is the seprator to get the Nodes
$Nodes = $DesiredOutput -split '\*'

# variable to store the output 
$output = $null

# loop through each node and get the corresponding
# values and store it in the output variable

foreach($Node in $Nodes)
{
    if($Node -match $Pattern ){

        $output += [string]($targetNode.Node.SelectSingleNode($Node).'#text') 
    }
    else{
        $output += $Node 
    }
}
#get the output 
$output
```